# How to read the information form a long text using Java

Tags: java, string

I have to translate a given text to another format.

For example, it is the given text:

```
#The number of cars that you can put in garage  = 4 
t1n1b2p2t1m1b2a2 
v1j1t1c1b3t1b1a1m1j1b4
```

I have to change it to:

```
#The number of cars that you can put in garage = 4 
Tesla Nissan BMW+ | Porsche+ Tesla Maserati | BMW+ Audi+ | 
Volvo Jaguar Tesla Cadillac | BMW++ Tesla | BMW Audi Maserati Jaguar  | BMW+++ |
```

But there is an other situation:

```
#The number of cars that you can put in garage is different
^3
t1b1t1b3
^2
m2a1t1
^4
a4v2p2
```

I have to change it to:

```
#The number of cars that you can put in garage is different
#Number of cars = 3
Tesla BMW Tesla | BMW++ | 
#Number of cars = 2
Maserati+ | Audi Tesla | 
#Number of cars = 4
Audi+++ | Volvo+ Porsche+ |
```

Comment: Your problem is not exactly clear to me. As long as you only want to translate strings like 't1n1b2p2t1m1b2a2' into 'Tesla Nissan BMW+ | Porsche+ ...' methods of the String class should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the code. Explanations after the code.

```java
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Garages {
    private static final Map<Character, String> CAR_MAKES = Map.of('a', "Audi",
                                                                   'b', "BMW",
                                                                   'c', "Cadillac",
                                                                   'j', "Jaguar",
                                                                   'm', "Maserati",
                                                                   'n', "Nissan",
                                                                   'p', "Porsche",
                                                                   't', "Tesla",
                                                                   'v', "Volvo");
    private static final Pattern REGEX = Pattern.compile("\\d+$");

    private static String handleLine(String line, int limit) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        int total = 0;
        char[] letters = line.toCharArray();
        for (int j = 0; j < letters.length; j++) {
            if (j % 2 == 0) {
                // should be a letter
                String make = CAR_MAKES.get(letters[j]);
                result.append(make);
            }
            else {
                // should be a number
                int amount = letters[j] - '0';
                for (int k = 1; k < amount; k++) {
                    result.append('+');
                }
                result.append(' ');
                total += amount;
                if (total >= limit) {
                    result.append("| ");
                    total = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    private static String handleLines(String[] lines) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        result.append(lines[0]);
        result.append(System.lineSeparator());
        Matcher matcher = REGEX.matcher(lines[0]);
        int limit = 0;
        boolean hasLimit = matcher.find();
        if (hasLimit) {
            limit = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group());
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
            if (hasLimit) {
                result.append(handleLine(lines[i], limit));
            }
            else {
                if (i % 2 == 1) {
                    // amount line
                    limit = Integer.parseInt(lines[i].substring(1));
                    result.append("#Number of cars = " + limit);
                }
                else {
                    result.append(handleLine(lines[i], limit));
                }
            }
            result.append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    private static String handleInput(String input) {
        return handleLines(input.split("\n"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String first = """
#The number of cars that you can put in garage  = 4
t1n1b2p2t1m1b2a2
v1j1t1c1b3t1b1a1m1j1b4
                """;
        System.out.println(handleInput(first));
        String second = """
#The number of cars that you can put in garage is different
^3
t1b1t1b3
^2
m2a1t1
^4
a4v2p2
                """;
        System.out.println("====================================================================");
        System.out.println(handleInput(second));
    }
}
```

- The above code is based solely on the data in your question and does not check for invalid data.
- The code uses [text blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/text_blocks/index.html) that were first added in JDK 13. (Refer to variables `first` and `second` in method `main` in above code.) In text blocks the line separator is `\n`.
- Static method `of` was added to [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface in JDK 9. I populated the map according to the data in your question.
- The `Map` key type must be a class (and not a primitive). Hence the key type is `java.lang.Character` (and not `char`). [Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) automatically converts the `char` literal to a `Character` object.
- The first line of the input determines how the rest of the input should be parsed and handled. I use a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) for this. I check to see whether the first line of the input ends in a number.
- After the first line, I assume that each subsequent line of the input is either `^` character followed by a number or a line where every odd character (i.e. first, third, fifth, etc) is a letter and every even character is a digit. Hence the code will probably throw an exception – or give incorrect results – if the input does not follow this pattern.

Hopefully, the rest of the code is clear and self-explanatory.

This is the result I get when I run the above code.

```
#The number of cars that you can put in garage  = 4
Tesla Nissan BMW+ | Porsche+ Tesla Maserati | BMW+ Audi+ | 
Volvo Jaguar Tesla Cadillac | BMW++ Tesla | BMW Audi Maserati Jaguar | BMW+++ | 

====================================================================
#The number of cars that you can put in garage is different
#Number of cars = 3
Tesla BMW Tesla | BMW++ | 
#Number of cars = 2
Maserati+ | Audi Tesla | 
#Number of cars = 4
Audi+++ | Volvo+ Porsche+ |
```